# Copy multiple cells into one cell via google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone tell me how I get multiple cells copied and merged into one cell via google script?

Here is the function I have written right now. The issue is that multiple cells from a source cell range will be exactly copied into the destination into multiple cells.

Instead, I want to just have it merged into one cell.

```
function copyToSheet() {
  var srcTitle=getActiveSheet().getRange("C7");
  var srcText=getActiveSheet().getRange("C22:C28");
  var srcOptions=getActiveSheet().getRange("C32:C41");
  var srcListings=getActiveSheet().getRange("C44:C60");

  var extractedValues = [srcTitle, srcText, srcOptions, srcListings]

  var dstTitle="C4";
  var dstText="D4";
  var dstOptions="E4";
  var dstListings="F4";


  var dstList = [dstTitle, dstText, dstOptions, dstListings]

  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < extractedValues.length; ++index) {
    extractedValues[index].copyTo(getDestinationSheet().getRange(dstList[index]), {contentsOnly:true})
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Copy To and Merge**

```
function copyToAndMerge() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//src sheet
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//des sheet
  var v=[];
  var rgA=['C7','C22:C28','C32:C41','C44:C60'];//input ranges  
  rgA.forEach(function(rg){
    var vA=ssh.getRange(rg).getValues();
    vA.forEach(function(r,i){v=v.concat(r);});
  });
  //Logger.log(v);
  //v.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});//if you want to sort the output this sorts numerically
  dsh.getRange(1,1).setValue(v.join(', '));//output cell you can change the delimiter
}
```

The output cell:

[image]

The input was just sequential numbers down column C.

Answer (score 0):

Got inspired by @cooper using the `dsh.getRange(1,1).setValue(v.join(', '));`

I was stuck thinking I could only run the copy function on the object. Instead, I could have just used the setValue function on a sheet object.

```
function copyToSheet() {
  var srcTitle=getActiveSheet().getRange("C7").getValue();
  var srcText=getActiveSheet().getRange("C22:C28").getValues();
  var srcOptions=getActiveSheet().getRange("C32:C41").getValues();
  var srcListings=getActiveSheet().getRange("C44:C60").getValues();

  var extractedValues = [srcTitle, srcText, srcOptions, srcListings]

  var dstTitle="C4";
  var dstText="D4";
  var dstOptions="E4";
  var dstListings="F4";


  var dstList = [dstTitle, dstText, dstOptions, dstListings]

  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < extractedValues.length; ++index) {
    getDestinationSheet().getRange(dstList[index]).setValue(extractedValues[index]);
  }

}
```